# Proving that X is not complete

Tags: self-study, inference, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

So, the question is the following:

"Be X a single sample from $Beta(\theta,\theta )$, is X a sufficient statistic? Is it complete?"

So, since it's the entire sample, it's easy to say that it is sufficient. I also know how to prove that it is NOT complete by proving that the distribution belongs to the exponential family and checking how $(C_{1}(\theta ), C_{2}(\theta ))$ does not contain an open set.

Now, What I want to know is if that what my other (easier) proof is correct:

"Given that $T$ is only complete if:

$E(g(T)) = 0$ implies that $P(g(T) = 0) = 1$ for all $\theta$

So, $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}$. Given $g(T) = X - \frac{1}{2}$, $E(g(T)) = E(X) - \frac{1}{2} = 0$.

but $P(X - \frac{1}{2} = 0) \neq  1$, so X is not complete."

Is that correct?

Comment: looks correct to me